# Clicking text to select checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

JSFiddle [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/u614sy0L/1/)

This is a list of checkboxes inside a dropdown menu. I would like to be able to click the anchor tags' text to select the corresponding checkbox. However, I currently have it set to `<a href="#">` which simply closes the dropdown and goes to top of page (on my own version, not JSFiddle, because it is on an overlay).

I saw a solution that selected the checkbox but the dropdown still closed on each click, is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: You could use a `<label>` instead.

Comment: you have not given the link its currently empty so 404

Comment: @gcampbell is it correct to have `<input>` inside of `<label>`?

Comment: @ToniAu yes: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/u614sy0L/2/

Comment: @ToniAu [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

Comment: @gcampbell Oh, I see now. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You can use labels for this functionality. Replace your `<ul>` list with this one.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check_1"/>
    <label for="check_1">Item 1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check_2"/>
    <label for="check_2">Item 2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check_3"/>
    <label for="check_3">Item 3</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This will help you

Comment: Also worth nothing that it's possible to put an `<input>` *inside* a `<label>`. (This still works though.)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var checkBox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
  checkBox.prop("checked", !checkBox.prop("checked"));
})
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<label for="display">Display</label><br/>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="display" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Select Options
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <input type="checkbox">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <input type="checkbox">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    
      <a href="#">
        <input type="checkbox">Item 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. However, would you have an idea as to why the dropdown closes after every click?

Answer (score 0):

you can achive it like this.

```
$('a').on("click",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var checkbox = $(this).children("input");
  $(checkbox[0]).attr('checked', !checkbox.attr('checked'));
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/u614sy0L/5/